# How to feed price from oracle and keep it up to date in another smart-contract?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

User interacts with contract, and I need to take a fee from this interaction. Like 1$.
I need stable 1$ equivalent of ETH.

Is there way to update this price ticker (ETH/USD) (well once a day is enough) before (!) user interact with contract? So when he sign it, I can ask for exact 1$ equivalent from his address?

Comment: Yes. just get the price in the function at first place. What network you deployed your contract?

Comment: Ethereum and EVM compatible. So look like I got it (priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);)?

Comment: Yes! Do you know how to use it or need help?!

Comment: I can. Thanks!x

Comment: Your welcome. Best regards :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes. just get the price in the function at first place.
> *by [Ahmad Gorji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69148380/how-to-feed-price-from-oracle-and-keep-it-up-to-date-in-another-smart-contract/69154446#comment122220349_69148380)*